# xamarin.forms: System.IO.IOException: Sharing violation on path PropertyStore.forms

Tags: android, xamarin.forms

xamarin.forms : On my android app, when i hit the home button or back button or try to take a picture with the Plugin.Media.
I use in my project [JamesMontemagno , Xamarin.Plugins](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/Xamarin.Plugins) .
i get the 
**following error:**

```
UNHANDLED EXCEPTION:

System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.IO.IOException: Sharing violation on path PropertyStore.forms

at System.IO.FileStream..ctor (System.String path, System.IO.FileMode mode, System.IO.FileAccess access, System.IO.FileShare share, System.Int32 bufferSize, System.Boolean anonymous, System.IO.FileOptions options) [0x0026d] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/4468/f913a78a/source/mono/mcs/class/corlib/System.IO/FileStream.cs:249 
at System.IO.FileStream..ctor (System.String path, System.IO.FileMode mode, System.IO.FileAccess access, System.IO.FileShare share, System.Int32 bufferSize, System.Boolean isAsync, System.Boolean anonymous) [0x00000] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/4468/f913a78a/source/mono/mcs/class/corlib/System.IO/FileStream.cs:149 
at System.IO.IsolatedStorage.IsolatedStorageFileStream..ctor (System.String path, System.IO.FileMode mode, System.IO.FileAccess access, System.IO.FileShare share, System.Int32 bufferSize, System.IO.IsolatedStorage.IsolatedStorageFile isf) [0x00000] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/4468/f913a78a/source/mono/mcs/class/corlib/System.IO.IsolatedStorage/IsolatedStorageFileStream.cs:127 
at System.IO.IsolatedStorage.IsolatedStorageFileStream..ctor (System.String path, System.IO.FileMode mode, System.IO.IsolatedStorage.IsolatedStorageFile isf) [0x00000] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/4468/f913a78a/source/mono/mcs/class/corlib/System.IO.IsolatedStorage/IsolatedStorageFileStream.cs:142 
at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.IO.IsolatedStorage.IsolatedStorageFileStream:.ctor (string,System.IO.FileMode,System.IO.IsolatedStorage.IsolatedStorageFile)
at System.IO.IsolatedStorage.IsolatedStorageFile.OpenFile (System.String path, System.IO.FileMode mode) [0x00000] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/4468/f913a78a/source/mono/mcs/class/corlib/System.IO.IsolatedStorage/IsolatedStorageFile.cs:908 
at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.IO.IsolatedStorage.IsolatedStorageFile:OpenFile (string,System.IO.FileMode)
at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.Deserializer+<>c.b__1_0 () [0x00006] in C:\BuildAgent3\work\ca3766cfc22354a1\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\Deserializer.cs:22 
at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[TResult].InnerInvoke () [0x00012] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/4468/f913a78a/source/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/threading/Tasks/Future.cs:680 
at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute () [0x00016] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/4468/f913a78a/source/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/threading/Tasks/Task.cs:2502
```

**this is my AndroidManifest.xml :**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:installLocation="auto" package="MY_PACKAGE_NAME" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="21" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BATTERY_STATS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_PRIVILEGED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAPTURE_VIDEO_OUTPUT" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <application android:label="MyApp" android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:largeHeap="true">
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY" android:value="MY_GOOGLE_API_KEY" />
        <provider android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider" android:authorities="MY_PACKAGE_NAME.fileprovider" android:exported="false" android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS" android:resource="@xml/file_paths"></meta-data>
        </provider>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

**scenario that causes the exception i wrote above:**
1. Start the application in my android/emulator.
2. The splash screen finishes to load and i am transferred to my login page.
3. When i am on my login page , i click the home button or back button .
4. I get the exceptio i have mentioned above.

I cant understad according to this callstack what is the origin of the error,
but if some one had the same exception and found a solution i ll be happy to hear for a solution.

Comment: might want to take a minute to format your question so it is easier to read

Comment: Two things you could check: 1) do you have the correct Android permissions set? and 2) is there a possibility that 2 or more threads are accessing the same resource at the same time? Media.Plugin is https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/MediaPlugin?

Comment: Hi, i have formatted the question so it is more cleare.

Comment: Hi @surin, I am also facing same exception. Have you got any solution or exact cause of this type of issue. And crash reporting from iPhone give System.UnauthorizedAccessException for same file.
Thanks.